# Given lodash map, how to limit the # of results or slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have the following:

```
import itemsMap from '../libs/items-map';
const _ = require('lodash');
const options = {};

_.map(itemsMap, (item, key) => {
  options[key] = key;
});
```

I then output in React like so:

```
  {
    _.map(itemsMap, (item, key) => (
        {key}
      />
    ))
  }
```

This currently outputs the entire items list,, I would like to output only 5.. I tired using slice like so:

```
  {
    _.map(itemsMap.slice(2), (item, key) => (
        {key}
      />
    ))
  }
```

This results in a TypeError: `.default.slice is not a function`

How can I limit the results?

Comment: Why use `lodash.map`? Why not just use built-in `array.map` on the keys of the object: `Object.keys(itemsMap).slice(0,5).map(...// rest of code)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever loader/bundler is resolving your `import` isn't exposing `itemsMap` as an array. You may need to use `require` syntax like the 2 lines below that.

Also, since the `key` in your return statement is wrapped in curly brackets but no jsx tags, it's parsed as an object and doesn't render anything. see what happens on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mdarens/pen/zWdGMX?&editors=0010) when you remove the `<span>` around `{key}`.

To your original question, the idiomatic way to limit items in lodash would be to use [lodash.take](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#take) like so:

`_.map(_.take(itemsMap, 2), (item, key) => ( … ))`

Comment: Thanks but that results in nothing being displayed, no JS error either...